# Struts 2 portlets postback redirect to URL

Tags: redirect, struts2, tomcat7, action, portlet

1. Using struts 2.3 with portlets and I have have tried everything possible to make an action redirect on postback without success.

   Purpose is to post form, save it temporarily, then navigate user to another page.
2. > @Result(name = "redirect", location = "http://www.google.com", type = "redirect")

   Doing this always gives me an exception:

   > Nested Exception is javax.portlet.PortletException: Could not locate dispatcher for 'http://www.google.com' at org.apache.struts2.portlet.result.PortletResult.executeMimeResult(PortletResult.java:213)
3. How to make this work?

Comment: See this: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4891363.

Comment: I think that's specific to the LifeRay Portal. We are using Apache's Pluto Portal. I do agree that there must be something special about redirecting from a portlet, it isn't as simple as all the examples existing for regular struts2 redirect.

Comment: Maybe url constructing part is liferay specific. But `actionResponse.sendRedirect("http://www.yahoo.com");` is standard portlet action response.

Comment: Thx. Doing that inside action method gave error: "Nested Exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't invoke setRenderParameter() after sendRedirect() has been called"

I have been trying to run sendRedirect in a method annotated with @After (AnnotationWorkflowInterceptor) to see if that fixes above error but I cannot get that method to run. I must be setting up the AnnotationWorkflowInterceptor wrong.